# PL/SQL vs SQL Query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a large Oracle project where I have 150+ tables. Most of the times I have small SQL Queries where I insert or retrieve columns of data. I want to use only PL/SQL blocks to work with the tables. Is this a good approach considering the fact that most of the times I will have small SQL queries?

Comment: I was tempted to write *yes* as an answer, but then I don't know if that had helped you.

Comment: Can you share some experience?

Comment: Peter, you should provide more context to receive a meaningful answer. Good in what sense ? : performance, manageability, clarity, etc. Working with straightforward data sets generally SQL out performs PL/SQL (is performance an issue?), when you need a lot of conditional logic PL/SQL delivers more readable code, PL/SQL (Functions, procedures) can be stored in the database which will increase manageability, and so on ...

Comment: How one can even answer this if we don't know what tools you use to access your data? How you save and present resultsets? To me, sounds like the answer is  - you can do whatever you want, whatever makes you comfortable. But then I ask myself, why `Select a, b From T` needs pl/sql?

Comment: If you're looking at Table API's then have a look at this discussion: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:672724700346558185 (or search asktom.oracle.com for "tapi" and you'll have some food for thought.)

Answer (score 1):

SQL and PLSQL both are different engines. If you are doing something with PLSQL, both PLSQL as well as SQL engines will be hit. Thats why its preferred to complete your task with SQL as far as possible as it will be quick and efficient. But again a lot of things depends on requirement.